# How to do conditional ("if exist" logic) search & replace in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, search, replace, conditional-statements

in my Perl script I want to do conditional search & replace using regular expression: Find a certain pattern, and if the pattern exists in a hash, then replace it with something else.

For example, I want to search for a combination of "pattern1" and "pattern2", and if the latter exists in a hash, then replace the combination with "pattern1" and "replacement". I tried the following, but it just doesn't do anything at all.

```
$_ =~ s/(pattern1)(pattern2)/$1replacement/gs if exists $my_hash{$2};
```

I also tried stuff like:

```
$_ =~ s/(pattern1)(pattern2) && exists $my_hash{$2}/$1replacement/gs;
```

Also does nothing at all, as if no match is found.

Can anyone help me with this regex problem? Thx~

Comment: How doesn't it work, error? just does nothing ?

Comment: Hang on ... so patt2 should exist in some hash somewhere, OK; but the combination of patt1 and patt2 should exist ... in some string? Is this correct?

Comment: @123 no error; it just does nothing.

Comment: @zdim well, pattern2 REALLY exist in the hash. pattern1 does not have anything to do with the hash; I use such a "combination" just to illustrate that pattern2 should be matched in a certain context.

Comment: OK ... and then patt1-patt2 combination is sought and if it exists it is replaced with patt1-else? Is that what you want? I posted a quick answer, see and let  me know.

Comment: @katyusza Should give an warning `Use of uninitialized value $2 in exists at perltest line 8.`

Comment: @zdim Right; this is what I want. I'm reading your answer now ~ ;-)

Comment: @123 Thanks for your hints; unfortunately I disabled the "warning" stuff at the beginning.

Comment: @katyusza Yeah don't do that.

Comment: @123 Thanks for the hint; I just habitually omitted that -____-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it a different way. It looks like you have a 'search this, replace that' hash.

So:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

#our 'mappings'. 
#note - there can be gotchas here with substrings
#so make sure you anchor patterns or sort, so 
#you get the right 'substring' match occuring. 

my %replace = (
    "this phrase" => "that thing",
    "cabbage"     => "carrot"
);

#stick the keys together into an alternation regex. 
#quotemeta means regex special characters will be escaped. 
#you can remove that, if you want to use regex in your replace keys.     
my $search = join( "|", map {quotemeta} keys %replace );
#compile it - note \b is a zero width 'word break' 
#so it will only match whole words, not substrings. 
$search = qr/\b($search)\b/;

#iterate the special DATA filehandle - for illustration and a runnable example. 
#you probably want <> instead for 'real world' use. 
while (<DATA>) {
    #apply regex match and replace
    s/(XX) ($search)/$1 $replace{$2}/g;
    #print current line. 
    print;
}

##inlined data filehandle for testing. 
__DATA__
XX this phrase cabbage
XX cabbage carrot cabbage this phrase XX this phrase
XX no words here
and this shouldn't cabbage match this phrase at all
```

By doing this, we turn your hash keys into a regex (you can print it - it looks like: `(?^:\b(cabbage|this\ phrase)\b)`

Which is inserted into the substitution pattern. This will *only* match if the key is present, so you can safely do the substitution operation.

Note - I've added `quotemeta` because then it escapes any special characters in the keys. And the `\b` is a "word boundary" match so it doesn't do substrings within words. (Obviously, if you *do* want that, then get rid of them)

The above gives output of:

```
XX that thing cabbage
XX carrot carrot cabbage this phrase XX that thing
XX no words here
and this shouldn't cabbage match this phrase at all
```

If you wanted to omit lines that *didn't* pattern match, you can stick `&& print;` after the regex.

Comment: Still can't completely wrap my mind around it but it's beautiful :)

Comment: It's fairly straightforward - you create a (possibly really long) regex match expression using alternation. That alternation 'captures' `$2`, which you then use in the right hand side of the substitution. There are a few gotchas though, around possible substrings, which means you sometimes have to sort the keys by length.

Comment: Yeah, your code is nice!! To say the truth, I did spend some time trying to figure the usage of "map", "qr" and "compile" stuffs, but failed. Now I'm simply using your code "as is", without knowing what it actually means, and it really works in my code! Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong (as in not working) with

```
if (exists($h{$patt1)) { $text =~ s/$patt1$patt2/$patt1$1replacement/g; }
```

If `$patt1` exists as a key in a hash then you go ahead and replace `$patt1$patt2` with `$patt1$replacement`.  Of course, if `$patt1$patt2` is found in `$text`, otherwise nothing happens.  Your first code snippet is circular, while the second one can't work like that at all.

If you want `$patt1$patt2` first, *and* hash key as well then it seems that you'd have to go slow

```
if ($str =~ /$patt11$patt2/ && exists $h{$patt2}) {
     $str =~ s/$patt1$patt2/$patt1$replacement/gs;
}
```

If this is what you want then it is really simple: you need two unrelated conditions, whichever way you turn it around. Can't combine them since it would be circular.

From the point of view of the outcome these are the same.  If either condition fails nothing happens, regardless of the order in which you check them.

**NOTE** Or maybe you don't have to go slow, see [Sobrique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2566198/sobrique)'s post.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not what I intended. What I really want is: FIRST, search for $patt1$patt2; THEN, if match is found AND if $patt2 exists in hash, then replace it with $patt1$replacement.

Comment: The new added code does not work either. As for the reason, well, my intention comes from the thing I'm trying to do: Given a text file, I want to find all Dffs and replace them with a new name. Here "Dffs" appear in format like "reg foo1" or "reg [3:0] foo2", but the stuff after "reg" may or may NOT be a Dff. Only if "reg foo3" AND "foo3" exist in Dff hash, foo3 is regarded as a Dff. There may be many Dffs in the file; I need to find-and-replace them all.

Comment: So you have "reg text-to-replace", but to replace it only if BOTH "text-to-replace" and "reg text-to-replace" are keys in a hash?  Both of them? Btw, what is a "Dff" -- your name for these things you work with? What is "Dff hash", simply a hash that has keys which are involved in strings to manipulate?

Comment: This reallly makes it completely different and I will remove this pointless "answer" once you update the question (since the explanation in these comments changes the question, I think), if you wish to do so.  I suggest that you do if you want useful ideas.

Comment: The answer given by Sobrique exactly does what I want. Thank you ;-)